# Bot Framework React Web Chat Adaptive Card execute action

Tags: reactjs, botframework, adaptive-cards

Is there a way for the Microsoft Bot Framework React Web Chat component to render Adaptive Cards which contain an execute action and send an execute message when the execute action button is clicked?

When clicking the execute button of an Adaptive Card which contains an action of type Action.Execute (which was [introduced in schema version 1.4](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Execute.html)), the action is not performed and an error is displayed in the browser console:

`Web Chat: received unknown action from Adaptive Cards`

Examining the [AdaptiveCardRenderer.tsx](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/db38effae0e17fc1ca31187356299fd0ec025444/packages/bundle/src/adaptiveCards/Attachment/AdaptiveCardRenderer.tsx#L158) file which this error is thrown from shows that only the action types Action.OpenUrl and Action.Submit are handled in the code.

The [adaptive card designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) says that Web Chat only supports up to v1.3 of the schema

`[Warning] The selected Target Version (1.4) is greater than the version supported by Bot Framework WebChat (1.3)`

However, I'm using the Bot Framework React Web Chat component v4.15.2. According to the [FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/4234) on GitHub, this version of the Web Chat component should support Adaptive Cards with schema version up to 1.5 by default which seems to contradict the above.